# Set permissions for a custom folder in a Visual Studio setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, setup-project, setup-deployment, special-folders

I need to store program settings that can be read/write for all accounts.  In the setup project, I will create a program specific folder for the settings under the CommonApplicationData special folder (Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData).  By default this folder would be read only to non-Administrator accounts.

Is there a way in the Visual Studio (2013) setup project to change the permissions to this new folder to Full Control for Everyone?  I would like to do this in the setup instead of at run-time of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to change permissions on a directory. This means that you need to write a custom action to do it, so if you know what the code is then put it in a custom action.

Other MSI creation tools have support for the the LockPermissions table in the MSI (but you'd need to use Orca and figure out the required values), or extension custom actions (like WiX Util Permissions).